# Convert Swipe left / right to vertical scroll in react / gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, framer-motion

I'm bulding a site based on this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/5crke?file=/src/SmoothScroll.js

I'm new to react / gatsby and can't figure out how to detect horizontal swipe and make the page scroll left or right .. basicly: detecting swipe and convert it to vertical scroll.

Hope i'm clear enough :-)

Thx!

I tried to detect swipe with this, but without succes:

```
  const [touchStart, setTouchStart] = useState(null);
  const [touchEnd, setTouchEnd] = useState(null);

  const onTouchStart = (e) => {
    setTouchEnd(null);
    setTouchStart(e.targetTouches[0].clientX);
  };

  const onTouchMove = (e) => setTouchEnd(e.targetTouches[0].clientX);

  const onTouchEnd = () => {
    if (!touchStart || !touchEnd) return;
    const distance = touchStart - touchEnd;
  };
```